# Increase space by growing mdadm RAID10 from 4 to 6 (and more)

Tags: software-raid, mdadm, raid10

I'm running Centos 7.8 with mdadm v4.1

I have 4 NVMe (3.2TB each) configured in a RAID 10, so 50% usable space (6.4TB):

> Personalities : [raid10]
> md0 : active raid10 nvme5n1p16 nvme4n1p15 nvme0n1p1[4] nvme3n1p1[3] nvme2n1p1[2] nvme1n1p1[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIXAY.png)
> 6250967040 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]
> bitmap: 0/47 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

I am trying to increase usable space by adding 2 more NVMe for this result :
[image]

After executing the grow command, I have this :

> /dev/md0:
> Version : 1.2
> Creation Time : Wed Sep 23 15:51:45 2020
> Raid Level : raid10
> Array Size : 6250967040 (5961.39 GiB 6400.99 GB)
> Used Dev Size : 3125483520 (2980.69 GiB 3200.50 GB)
> Raid Devices : 6
> Total Devices : 6
> Persistence : Superblock is persistent
>
> ```
>  Intent Bitmap : Internal
>
>    Update Time : Fri Sep 25 11:03:05 2020
>          State : clean, reshaping
> Active Devices : 6    Working Devices : 6
> Failed Devices : 0
>  Spare Devices : 0
>
>         Layout : near=2
>     Chunk Size : 512K
> ```
>
> Consistency Policy : bitmap
>
> ```
> Reshape Status : 5% complete
>  Delta Devices : 2, (4->6)
>
>           Name : db04:0  (local to host db04)
>           UUID : a0d10c0a:fd5fb830:e986407d:5dca539b
>         Events : 7983
>
> Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
>    4     259        7        0      active sync set-A   /dev/nvme0n1p1
>    1     259        6        1      active sync set-B   /dev/nvme1n1p1
>    2     259        5        2      active sync set-A   /dev/nvme2n1p1
>    3     259        2        3      active sync set-B   /dev/nvme3n1p1
>    6     259       11        4      active sync set-A   /dev/nvme5n1p1
>    5     259       10        5      active sync set-B   /dev/nvme4n1p1
> ```

The array size is still 6.4TB and not 9.6TB. It seems like it's doing 3 copies of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out, the final array size of 9.6TB is effective and displayed only after the reshaping.